# What does the first argument of Function::Call in V8 Engine mean?

Tags: node.js, v8

In node-addon-example, [line 11 of `3_callbacks/addon.cc`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/blob/b2737e89abd00b7fc4468b38893b31c57c7d8fd9/3_callbacks/node_0.10/addon.cc#L11) reads:

```
cb->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

[V8's documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.10/d5/d54/classv8_1_1_function.html#a111b53439348e8726a5100ca5619484c) shows that:

```
V8EXPORT Local<Value> v8::Function::Call(Handle<Object> recv,
    int argc,
    Handle<Value> argv[]
);
```

So `Context::GetCurrent()->Global()` is used as `Handle<Object> recv`.

But what does `recv` stand for? What does it mean? And why is it appropriate to use `Context::GetCurrent()->Global()` in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same as `apply` in JS. In JS, you do

```
var context = ...;
cb.apply(context, [ ...args...]);
```

The object passed as the first argument becomes `this` within the function scope. More documentation on [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). If you don't know JS well, you can read more about JS's `this` here: http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/